# Notation for Strongly Noetherian Tate k-algebra?

Tags: number-theory, rigid-analytic-spaces

[image: H]

Hey! I am confused with some of the notation - not only in this definition, but also a little bit throughout (section 2 of) Peter Scholze's thesis *Perfectoid Spaces*. In this situation, what are the T's? I'm not sure :/

Help here would be very much appreciated :)

Comment: I'm sure he is **defining** $R\langle T_1,\ldots,T_n\rangle$ to be the thing on the RHS.

Comment: @AnginaSeng yeah, that's not really the biggest problem for me tbh - I'm just not sure what the T's are...

Comment: I presume just indeterminates ....